# SQL Azure TEXTPTR is not supported

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database

According to the [Features that are not support in  SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336281.aspx#Unsupported), TEXTPTR and UPDATETEXT aren't supported in Azure's SQL Database. Is there another way that can be used to insert/update big text/image fields, so that we can avoid having the entire column contents in memory?

Comment: Although I have not yet checked it out myself these functions are part of the new features coming with SQL Azure update V12, see the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336281.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATETEXT is depricated since SQL Server 2005. You should use [UPDATE ... SET ... .WRITE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523(v=sql.120).aspx#LOBValues) instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. In this case I had to use the [Stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) function